# What is relational parametricity?

Tags: programming-languages

A complicated-sounding term with no good explanations from a simple google search... are there any more academically-oriented folk who could explain this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relational parametricity seems to be the property that a function abstracted over types (like a generic in Java) can have. If it has this property, it means it never inspects its type argument or deconstructs it / uses it in some special way. For example, the function "id or inc" here is not relationally parametric:

```
public class Hey<T>
{
    public T idOrInc(T var)
    {
        if (var instanceof Integer)
            return (T)(new Integer(((Integer)var).intValue()+1));
        return var;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hey<Integer> h = new Hey<Integer>();
        System.out.println(h.idOrInc(new Integer(10)));
        Hey<Double> h2 = new Hey<Double>();
        System.out.println(h2.idOrInc(new Double(10)));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
$ java Hey
11
10.0
```

Answer (score 8):

Both answers are mostly right. I would say that parametricity is a possible property of polymorphism. And polymorphism is parametric if polymorphic terms behave the same under all instantiations. To "behave the same" is a vague, intuitive term. Relational parametricity was introduced by John Reynolds as a mathematical formalization of this. It states that polymorphic terms preserve all relations, which intuitively forces it to behave the same:

Consider f: a list -> a list.
  If we have the relation a~1, b~2, c~3, ..., then we can lift it to lists and hav e.g.
  [a, d, b, c] ~ [1, 4, 2, 3]

Now, if f([a, d, b, c]) = [c, b, d, a] and f preserves relations,
  then f([1, 4, 2, 3]) = [3, 2, 4, 1].
  In other words, if f reverses list of strings, it also reverses lists of numbers.

So relationally parametric polymorphic functions cannot "inspect the type argument", in that they cannot alter their behaviour based on the type.

Answer (score 1):

Relational parametricity is a technique for proving the statement that any fully parametric code will satisfy certain laws.

"Fully parametric" code is a function with type parameters, whose arguments are typed using only those type parameters, and whose code is purely functional and does not try to examine at run time what types are assigned to the type parameters. The code must treat all types as totally unknown.

With these restrictions, the code will satisfy a certain law, in most cases this will be the "naturality" law, but in some cases the law will be more complicated. The paper "Theorems for free" shows many examples of such laws.

To prove that those laws always hold, one uses the technique of relational parametricity. This is a complicated and powerful technique where one replaces functions (viewed as many-to-one binary relations) by arbitrary (many-to-many) binary relations and then reformulates the naturality law in terms of relations. The result is a "relational naturality law". At the end, one replaces relations again by functions and tries to derive an equation.

I recently recorded a tutorial about relational parametricity, with code examples in Scala. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jf2VFB90Q0s&list=PLcoadSpY7rHUO0I1zdcbu9EeByYbwPSQ6

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just going to hazard a COMPLETE guess here, based on this

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4276578

I'd say it's a mathematical representation of parametric polymorphism (generics).