# Functions that can be deduced by their type signature

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was introduced to this idea informally by this c++ talk [Ben Deane “Using Types Effectively"](https://youtu.be/ojZbFIQSdl8?si=va5qqMZTlI2rrETo&t=1766)

For example:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
T f(pair<T, U>);
```

can be deduced to be `first`.

- What is the proper terminology for this?
- Are there some resources to learn more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Young already answered this in the comments of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589988/a-b-z-a-b-z).

> Regarding functions with only one possible implementation: This is the result of something called "parametricity". Sometimes it is not only one implementation, but the collection of possible implementations is very restricted. This fact is expressed by a "free theorem." Every parametrically polymorphic function has an associated free theorem. Some resources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369065/2476735), [2](https://well-typed.com/blog/2015/05/parametricity/), [3](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Edreyer/tor/papers/wadler.pdf), [4](https://people.mpi-sws.org/%7Edreyer/tor/papers/reynolds.pdf)

Comment: This is the correct answer, IMO, but note that in C++ (the language you used in your example), parametricity does _not_ hold. In C++ it's possible to implement `f(pair<T,U> x)` as (pseudo-code, not actual C++) `{ if (T == int) { return 42; } else { return x; } }`, which breaks the free theorems. Roughly put, C++ has "ad-hoc polymorphism" instead of "parametric polymorphism". (In Haskell this is feasible but only if we change the type: ad-hoc polymorphism must be exposed in the type signature.)